# Type or namespace 'jQuery' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reference, package

in my index.cshtml I get this that I'm missing a namespace or reference, I don't get why because I have that reference.  I have rebuilt, installed/uninstalled the package, I have closed solution reopened, cleaned.  Not sure why it can't find the reference.  Any help would be great.[image]

Comment: After a little investigation, im 99% sure that the DNX SDK 1.0.0-rc1 doesn't support any namespaces that include any microsoft ajax libraries.  Being on the brink of ASP core technology we just gotta wait a little bit to get our cake and eat it too.  However is anyone knows of any references where I canget Ajax.Beginform id like to know thanks!